# Typecast callback functions

Tags: c++, casting, callback

Can I typecast callback functions?

I like to write a library that registers and calls certain callback functions.

```
int MyCaller::add_callback_function(int (*callback_function)(), byte behaviour) {
    this->callback = callback_function;
}

void MyCaller::run() {
    int result = this->callback();
}

// ....

int get_number() { return 42; }
MyCaller my_caller;
my_caller.add_callback_function(get_number, 0);
my_caller.run();
```

However, I would also like to support callback_functions that output a boolean.

```
bool get_bool() { return true; }
MyCaller my_caller;
my_caller.add_callback_function(get_number, 0);
my_caller.run();
```

If I try this, my code seems to run fine, but gcc will give a `warning: invalid conversion from 'bool (*)()' to 'int (*)()' [-fpermissive]`.

To avoid this warning, I overloaded my `add_callback_function` with a slightly different signature:

```
void MyCaller::add_callback_function(bool (*callback_function)(), byte behaviour) {
    // ...
}
```

However, I'm lost from this point onward. I expected that I could cast any boolean to an integer, and call the original method:

```
void MyCaller::add_callback_function(bool (*callback_function)(), byte behaviour) {
    this->add_callback_function(static_cast<int (*)()>(callback_function), byte behaviour);
}
```

However, this gives an `error: invalid static_cast from type 'bool (*)()' to type 'int (*)()'`.

So I seem to be doing something wrong.

Is there a clean way to do this?

For bonus points: My code stores an array of callback functions, and I like to be able to optionally add a context parameter (to e.g. allow calling methods besides functions). I plan to store all these callbacks (with different signatures) as a `int (*)()`, and typecast them to their proper form before calling them. Would that be the best way, or are there other (perhaps better) ways to handle this?

The alternative I can think of is to only support one very specific callback signature, but that forces users to write wrappers. I like to put that burden on the library.

Comment: This is a horrible idea (even if it were possible). Coercing different signatures into a single signature is a good way to corrupt the call stack if you are not careful. If you have callbacks that use different signatures, then store them in separate arrays of appropriate types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So you clearly don't recommend going this route. What would you recommend? Only allow one callback signature? FYI, the reality is slightly more complex. My original code took a callback that returned a bool. I now like to extend my code to accept an int, but be backward compatible.

Comment: "*Only allow one callback signature?*" - basically, yes. That is the only *sane* thing to do. The caller of the callbacks (`run()`) needs to know which signature to use to call each callback, and unless you are prepared to type-cast every callback to a different signature based on some tracking data you have associated with each callback, it is far easier to just deal with 1 signature. So what if the user needs to use wrappers for different signatures - that is what lambdas are good for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast one function pointer type to another, **but** you can only call it if you cast it to the *real* function pointer type.  You can only store them as the wrong signature.

Calling them any other way results in undefined behavior.  The most likely symptom will depend on your platforms current calling convention.  But really, just don't do it.

The easiest correct solution is to store a

```
std::function<int()>
```

this isn't a function pointer, but can store any callback (including a function pointer) that can be copied, moved, and invoked with zero arguments and returns something compatible with an `int` (which a `bool` qualifies as).

`std::function` can also store objects with state.  For example:

```
struct Foo {
  int count = 0;
  int callback(){ return ++count; }
};

Foo foo;
std::function<int()> f = [&foo]{ return foo.callback(); };
```

naturally you become responsible for lifetime.  Look up "C++ lambdas" to understand the above syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I fear I have to rethink some design. This is actually for a hobby project for an Arduino. Unfortunately, the logic is rather stateful, and I found my self replication the code that polled certain things (checking input, blinking lights, handling exceptions), with each snippet a different signature. So I wrote this small library. I doubt that `std::function` is the right approach for that platform (if it is supported at all). So I fear I'm back to square one replicating these pollers in multiple places. That or think of a common callback signature, and write lots of wrappers.

Comment: @macfreek lambdas can be used to wrap functions, if not pointers; `+[]()->int{return boolfunc();}` is function pointer to the int returning function that calls boolfunc.  Also roll your own allocation free std function is 150 or so lines of code.